# reactjs, looping json, conditional divs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to reactjs, looping through a set of json that will provide a footer menu.

**Really stuck*** Whats the solution for this kind of outerwrapping requirement

The markup I need to recreate looks like this.

```
<div class="row">     
        <div class="main-footer__left">
            <div class="row grid__row--offset--30">
                <div class="large-45 large-centered columns">
                    <h2 class="text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text">Col</h2>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-footer__right">
            <div class="row grid__row--offset--30">

                <div class="large-14 large-offset-5 columns">
                    <h2 class="text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text">Col</h2>   
                </div>
                <div class="large-1 columns">
                    <div class="vert-line--light-blue"></div>
                </div>


                <div class="large-14 large-offset-5 columns">
                    <h2 class="text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text">Col</h2>   
                </div>
                <div class="large-1 columns">
                    <div class="vert-line--light-blue"></div>
                </div>


                <div class="large-14 large-offset-5 columns">
                    <h2 class="text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text">Col</h2>                    
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row grid__row--offset--30">
                <div class="large-15 large-centered columns">
                    <p class="text--white text--center footer-text">FIXED</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so on the 0 index -- needs to outwrap the col with the "left" class -- from index 1 -- needs to wrap ALL other items inside the "right" class

my current reactjs code looks like this -- but I am struggling to add the outerwrappers.

```
    {
      lang.menu.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
          {
            index === 0 ? <div className='main-footer__left' /> : null
          }
        {/*
        <div key={index} className='large-14 large-offset-5 columns'>
          <h2 className='text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text'>{item.title}</h2>
          {
            item.switch
              ? <p className='text--white grid__row--offset--15 footer-text'>
                {
                  item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                    return (
                      <Link key={j} className={'text--white footer-text transition ' + (props.active_language === child.title.toString().toLowerCase() ? activeLang : alternativeLang)} to={urls[j]}>{child.title}</Link>
                    )
                  })
                }
              </p>
              : item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                return (
                  <div key={j} className={(j === 0 ? ' grid__row--offset--15' : '')}>
                    <Link className='text--white footer-text transition' to={child.link}>{child.title}</Link>
                  </div>
                )
              })
          }
        </div>
        */}
        )
      })
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be new to React. You have react questions dating back nearly a year.

Comment: Still learning. What's the best way of creating this kind of outerwrapping on a loop?

Comment: any suggestions here - really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You're requirements are hard to understand, but you should be able to take this approach to achieve what you want. You might have to do a little tweaking to `content`, but this structure should work for you:

```
    {
      lang.menu.map(function (item, index) {
        const content =
        <div key={index} className='large-14 large-offset-5 columns'>
          <h2 className='text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text'>{item.title}</h2>
          {
            item.switch
              ? <p className='text--white grid__row--offset--15 footer-text'>
                {
                  item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                    return (
                      <Link key={j} className={'text--white footer-text transition ' + (props.active_language === child.title.toString().toLowerCase() ? activeLang : alternativeLang)} to={urls[j]}>{child.title}</Link>
                    )
                  })
                }
              </p>
              : item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                return (
                  <div key={j} className={(j === 0 ? ' grid__row--offset--15' : '')}>
                    <Link className='text--white footer-text transition' to={child.link}>{child.title}</Link>
                  </div>
                )
              })
          }
        </div>;
        if(index === 0){
            return (
                <div className='main-footer__left'>
                  {content}
                </div>
            )
        }else{
            return (
                <div className='main-footer__right'>
                  {content}
                </div>
            )
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: -- is there a way to just modify the push in the array I had?

Comment: What array do you mean? I don't see any `.push()` in the code snippet you posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm 100% understanding your requirements, but if I'm reading it right, it sounds like the first item should be wrapped with `<div class="main-footer__left">` and the rest wrapped with `<div class="main-footer__right">`. Assuming that's always the case, you could do something like:

```
renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <div className='large-14 large-offset-5 columns'>
        <h2 className='text--uppercase text--light-blue footer-text'>{item.title}</h2>
        {
          item.switch
            ? <p className='text--white grid__row--offset--15 footer-text'>
              {
                item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                  return (
                    <Link key={j} className={'text--white footer-text transition ' + (props.active_language === child.title.toString().toLowerCase() ? activeLang : alternativeLang)} to={urls[j]}>{child.title}</Link>
                  )
                })
              }
            </p>
            : item.children.map(function (child, j) {
              return (
                <div key={j} className={(j === 0 ? ' grid__row--offset--15' : '')}>
                  <Link className='text--white footer-text transition' to={child.link}>{child.title}</Link>
                </div>
              )
            })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="main-footer__left">
          { this.renderItem(lang.map[0]) }
        </div>

        <div className="main-footer__right">
          { lang.menu.map((item, index) => index > 0 && this.renderItem(item))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Using the `renderItem` method is to avoid duplicating any code. Personally, I would make that a separate Component, called something like FooterItem that could be called in place of `this.renderItem()`.

Comment: -- is there a way to just modify the push in the array I had?

Comment: I don't see a `push()` in your question at all.